# why can't I get my two divs to sit side by side

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to place two divs side by side, the right div with text and the left one with a picture but I cant get it to work, I tried to float them right and left but that didn't work.

Here is my code

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id ="pic">

    <img src="IMG_4847.jpg"alt="me"/>
    

</div>

<div id ="about">
  

    <h1>About Me</h1>

<p>Hello my name is Rebekah, I’m 23 and this is my blog </p>

</div>

</div>
```

```css
#about
{
 
 padding-left: 500px;
 padding-right: 100px;
 padding-top: 60px;

 
 
}

#pic
{
 padding-left: 110px;
 padding-top: 60px;

  
 
}
```

Comment: Because you haven't set any CSS rule for displaying those divs side by side!

Comment: `div`s have block display by default which prevents anything to be placed beside the div. So unless you change that you will never see two divs side by side.

Comment: This is incorrect `about`. Should be `#about`

Comment: like what? do you mean width or position? I tried both but they didn't work

Comment: Also your DOM tree above is invalid. It it not balanced.

Comment: @becky you have more closing </div> than open ones.

Comment: no I don't I just checked

Answer (score 2):

You need to `float` the elements:

`#pic` should be floated left

```
#pic {
    float:left;
}
```

`#about` should be floated right

```
#about {
    float:right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x19wwk9n/

You also need the `#` on your about tag within your `CSS` file.

Comment: @becky - it does from the fiddle I provided.

Comment: @becky - did you specify `#about` rather than `about` in your CSS file?

Comment: no I had a look at it and it doesn't

Comment: @DarrenDavies it works if you float both to the left.

Comment: @becky note that sum of the divs width must be equal or less of the screen width to be displayed inline

Comment: oh yes I forgot about this

Comment: I think you need to specify a width.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your CSS the float instruction. Try giving both parts this:

```
float: right;
```

Comment: tried that and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

give both the divs the property to stay side bi side this way:

```
#about
{
    padding-top: 60px;
    float: left;
}

#pic
{
    padding-top: 60px;
    float: left;



}
```

and in your html after the two divs:

```
    <div id="container">
  <div id ="pic">

    <img src="IMG_4847.jpg"alt="me"/>


</div>

<div id ="about">


    <h1>About Me</h1>

<p>Hello my name is Rebekah, I’m 23 and this is my blog </p>

</div>


<br style="clear:both;">
```

to reset the float property and keep the rest of the layout as you want it. Note I have removed a closing  tag that was not necessary

Comment: sadly this didn't work

Comment: @becky it works. You have to adjust divs size and padding. Sum of margin, padding, borders and divs size (of both) must be equal or less than the screen size. In any other case the second div will jump on the next row. I guess that padding was your test to float them so better remove them all

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
#about
{
    padding-left: 500px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#pic
{
    padding-left: 110px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display divs side by side using `float:left`. You can also get them to display side by side using `inline-block` and or `float:left` and `float:right` (*like others had mentioned*). There are actually multiple ways this can be achieved and each one will likely depend on what uses cases you are trying to work with.

**HTML:**

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    width:50%;
    border:1px solid;
    height:200px; 
    box-sizing:border-box;
    float:left;
}
```

*Note:* *I added height because there is no content. Just to help show you better visually. And the box-sizing is to help the box model take the border into account. Otherwise the 1px border would cause the second `div` to wrap under the first.*

**Recommendation:**

*Also instead of doing this..*

```
<div id="pic"></div>
<div id="about"></div>
```

*I would recommend this..*

```
<div class="column"></div>
<div class="column"></div>
```

*And then something like..*

```
.column {
        width:50%;
        border:1px solid;
        height:200px; 
        box-sizing:border-box;
        float:left;
    }
```

**Example:**

https://jsfiddle.net/4eocqjur/1/

Answer (score 0):

use `display: table`

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container{ 
   display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
#pic,
#about{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 25px;
}
#pic{
    background: #f00;
}
#about{
    background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id ="pic">
        <img src="IMG_4847.jpg"alt="me"/>
    </div>
    <div id ="about">
        <h1>About Me</h1>
        <p>Hello my name is Rebekah, I’m 23 and this is my blog </p>
    </div>
</div>
```